# Jquery Datepicker, Increment Of Year from Number Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I use this code for datepicker and want to increment of Year (Only Year from full date), which display on other field.. Currently It append number (type=number not working in firefox, good with chrome) field value to current year.

I want that if 5 in number field then it should display (2014 + 5) = 2019. But My code return 20145 as Year

Here Is **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/789Hv/)**

My Js Code Is Here.

```
        $( "#dtp" ).datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
             var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
                day  = date.getDate(),  
                month = date.getMonth() + 1,              
                year =  date.getFullYear() + 1;
                //alert(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);
                $('#popupDatepicker1').val(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);
         }
    });

    $('#user_lic').change(function(){
        var numberOfDaysToAdd = this.value;
        var date = $('#dtp').datepicker('getDate'),
        day  = date.getDate(),  
        month = date.getMonth() + 1,              
        year =  date.getFullYear() + numberOfDaysToAdd;
        $('#popupDatepicker1').val(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/789Hv/2/)

The numberOfDaysToAdd variable is being saved as a string, so it's being concatenated rather than added. Turn it into a float and this will work fine.

```
 var days2add =  parseFloat(numberOfDaysToAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unary operator to turn your `numberofDaysToAdd` to a `number`.

```
year =  date.getFullYear() + +numberOfDaysToAdd;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
$( "#dtp" ).datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
             var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
                day  = date.getDate(),  
                month = date.getMonth() + 1,              
                year =  date.getFullYear() + 1;
                //alert(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);
                $('#popupDatepicker1').val(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);
         }
    });

        $('#user_lic').change(function(){
        var numberOfDaysToAdd = parseInt(this.value);
        var date = $('#dtp').datepicker('getDate'),
        day  = date.getDate(),  
        month = date.getMonth() + 1,              
        year =  parseInt(date.getFullYear() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
        $('#popupDatepicker1').val(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);
    })
```